# Breakout clone, how to handle/design for collision detection/physics between objects?

Tags: collision-detection, physics

I'm working on a breakout clone, and I wish to create some realistic physics effects for collision - angles on the paddle should allow the ball to bounce, as well as doing curve balls etc. I could use per-pixel based collision detection, but then I thought it might be easier with line/circle intersection testing.

So, then I naturally consider making a polygon class for the line-based objects and use the built-in circle class for the circular objects. That sounds like an OK approach, right? And then just check for collision using the specified algorithm based on the objects that might be within each other's range?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That seems like a good approach, you can utilize the [separating axis theorem](http://www.metanetsoftware.com/technique/tutorialA.html) to perform your collision detection.